# Question sorting is kind of weird

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions

On main pages of sites, aren't posts supposed to appear with the most recently edited one at the top, and then go in order from most to least recently edited?

[image]

Decidedly unlike this picture. I've seen this a few times before, on the main site and on meta. What's going on?

Comment: It's a good thing I got a screenshot, because now it's in the right place.

Comment: Might be just a database quirk.

Comment: It's a caching thing. The order of questions is cached for slightly longer than the edited times seem to be. Seems worse  on Metas. UX has noticed it too http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/606/sorting-questions-by-time-is-sometimes-incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by-design, and a side effect of caching.

The question is *list* is cached for a short while, while the question details itself are always rendered up-to-date (for logged-in users).